# How to apply style to the Jquery datatable column depending on the column value

Tags: datatables

http://jsfiddle.net/ktdj3u9r/5/

I am uisng  Jquery DataTable to display data in a Tabular format .

My requirement is that if the quantity field is greater than 100000 , i want to display it in green color

This is my code

```js
var dataSet = 
    [
    [
        "1441.75",
        "238469"
    ],
    [
        "1614.45",
        "327663"

    ],
    [
        "834.15",
        "1583726"
    ],
    [
        "2261.85",
        "1062354"
    ],
    [
        "444.10",
        "99399"

    ]
];

var array_names = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];

for(var key in dataSet) {
    if(dataSet.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        //dataSet[key].unshift(array_names[key]);
        dataSet[key].splice(0,0,array_names[key]);
    }
} 

  $(function()
  {

        $('#allwl').dataTable( {
                  "iDisplayLength": -1,
        "data": dataSet,
        "columns": [
            { "title": "Name" },
            { "title": "Price" },
    {
   "title": "Quantity" ,
     mRender: function(data, type, row){
        var quantity = row[2] ;
        return quantity;
     }
    }
         ]
    } );   

  })
```

could you please let me know how to do this ??

Comment: I am getting the flat array data from backend and then i am showing that in my datatable , so   its client side .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [**`createdCell`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell) callback in yor quantity declaration :

```js
...
"columns": [
     { "title": "Name" },
     { "title": "Price" },
     { "title": "Quantity" ,
        mRender: function(data, type, row){
           var quantity = row[2] ;
           return quantity;
        },
        createdCell: function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
           if (cellData>100000) $(td).css('color', 'green');
        }
     }
]
...
```

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/5fbo72rm/**

Answer (score 0):

Use `fnRowCallback` for this:

```
"fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
         if(aData[2] > 100000){
             $('td:eq(2)', nRow).addClass("td-green");
         }
  }
```

This will add the class `td-green` to any value > 100000

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/markps/ktdj3u9r/6/

Comment: Could you please let me know where exactly to add this in the code , because i am getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string in browser console .

Comment: The code in your fiddle isn't still working , should i create a new class ??

Comment: @davidkonrad - thanks David, I pasted the unedited version by mistake!

Comment: @PreethiJain - I've updated the jsfiddle link, sorry about that.

Comment: @markpsmith , no problem , but still i cannot see the green color for the table td.